# Anaconda won't change environments for Jupyter, had to reboot. (Win 10)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, environment, reboot

In Anaconda Navigator, Environments screen, clicked on an env I'd used before on same system, loading bar went forever.  Then opened CMD.exe Prompt from Navigator, activated the environment and prompt showed directory to be running in the desired environment, but Jupyter couldn't import the env's packages.

I'm still somewhat new to all this, so the answer I'll post is likely far from the best solution but thought I'd contribute something.  I'll watch for any corrections to my process, thanks!

Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12
Jupyter Notebooks 6.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Please enlighten me with a better solution than rebooting, but this worked for me: First quit Jupyter, then activate desired environment through *anaconda* prompt as described below, then quit Anaconda and restart computer, then start Anaconda, click on desired environment (after loading, Navigator home screen 'applications on' drop-down should list this environment), then create a new notebook and try any imports unique to desired environment.

**Activate**
Given that you have already created the environment, in Anaconda prompt go to environment location (in my case this is where I had placed the environment yaml file):
`(base) C:\Users\Owner>cd location`
check environments:
`(base) C:\Users\Owner\location>conda env list`
Should return list of conda environments that includes:
`desired_environment      *  C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\envs\desired_environment`
Activate:
`(base) C:\Users\Owner\location>conda activate desired_environment`
Should return:
`(desired_environment) C:\Users\Owner\location>` 
Now go through remaining steps listed up top!